# Meaning of "site sbd" when working with mainframe PDS using Python ftplib

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, mainframe, ftplib

I have gone through the below link for connecting to mainframe and extracting files from a  PDS.

[Downloading text files with Python and ftplib.FTP from z/os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184844/downloading-text-files-with-python-and-ftplib-ftp-from-z-os)

But, am having few doubts on the line:

```
sess.sendcmd("site sbd=(IBM-1047,ISO8859-1)")
```

Could anyone please tell, what it stands for? When we write the `sess.sendcmd("site sbd=....")`, is this machine specific or is it a generic one?

Answer (score 3):

Text data on z/OS is (mostly) encoded in an EBCDIC code page, IBM-1047 being one of them. The z/OS FTP *server* is aware of the fact that text data outside z/OS is (mostly) encoded in some other (non-EBCDIC) code page, such as ISO8859-1. It therefore translates data when transfering in *text* (ASCII) mode (not binary or image mode). While the server has some default for both the z/OS side code page as well as the "network" side code page, you can change that default with:

```
SITE SBDATACONN=(file-system-cp,network-cp)
```

Where `file-system-cp` is the encoding used on the z/OS side and `network-cp` is the encoding in which the data is sent over the network, i.e. your non-z/OS encoding.